# Trigger Jenkins job by tag with Gitea

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, gitea

I work with Gitea and jenkins and I try to trigger a Jenkins job at the tag change in Gitea.

I installed the Gitea plugin and I have a multibranch pipeline with my repo in it.

I added the following line to my Pipeline:

```
refspec: '+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*'
```

I also checked this box in my Jenkins job:
[Poll SCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/220I6.png)

Unfortunately my job won't start, could you help me?

Thanks for everything